# Application Insights 2.4 on IIS 10 and .net framework 461 requires IIS reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-10, azure-application-insights

After I've updated Application Insights to version 2.4, I need to reset IIS after build the project changes. I reverted this and it started to work normally. I am using IIS on windows 10 64bits, with a dedicated application pool, on the root.

I tried to look around for some issue reported like this one but I couldn't find any information.

Do you guys have any idea of what can cause this and how to work around it?

Comment: Did any other dependencies change?

Comment: No, i tested with AI 2.0 and 2.4. When we use 2.0 everything works great, but when i update just the AI packages to the 2.4 version (and 2.4.1) this issue starts to happen. I just reset the IIS on the command line and it works great until i make changes to the project and rebuild it.

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that after upgrading to 2.4.1 any changes/build not related to Application Insights require IIS reset to take effect? And after rolling back no IIS reset is needed.

Comment: Right. With the application running on azure tests environment we don't have problems when publishing a newer version of the code. I think that this may be related to IIS in some way since most of the telemetry done in Azure is done on kestrel server..